# Custom texture autodesk forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Is it possible to show custom textures applied to materials in Revit using the forge viewer?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to use custom JavaScript to modify textures of the model after having translated it. If this is the case here is an example on how you can modify textures in the viewer: [Viewing.Extension.Material](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/tree/master/src/client/viewer.components/Viewer.Extensions.Dynamic/Viewing.Extension.Material)

You can test the live version using a revit model [here](https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator?id=59d52c493096fb09f0bfdcf2). Click the + from lower-right control and select "Office" for example.

[image]

Comment: Could we get an update on this topic? First link is dead and second returns 404 over the model.